# Received an email for a site still in closed beta when another site I was committed to went live

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email-notification

I committed to Pro Webmasters and Web Apps sites.  I just received an email saying that web apps went live and I fulfilled my commitment so I have gotten my commitment point back to put into another proposal.

I also received the same email for pro webmasters which has not left private beta yet.  The email includes a link to let others join up but obviously isn't working.  This appears to be a bug.

Comment: I thought commitment points are only returned after a site exits public beta...

Comment: @Maxim, I can't remember, but I've got two e-mails (Web Apps and Gaming) and if I now try to commit to another I'm told I have two "commits" left whereas previously I had none.

Comment: I got two emails from Gaming today, felt a little carpet-bombed.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, good point. We need to **update the email to reflect current private beta status**. Something like..

> Pro Webmasters is still in private beta for **1** more day.
>
> Once the site is public, please share a link to the site with anyone you think might be interested in our community:
>
> http://webmasters.stackexchange.com
>
> We hope you continue to visit Pro Webmasters and help it grow into a vibrant, useful community that benefits the internet at large.

Alternately, we might defer sending this until the second day of public beta at minimum. That would probably be easier.

Answer (score 1):

We thought about this some more and decided to not "release the commitment token" (i.e. consider the commitment fulfilled) until after the private beta has ended.

So, these emails won't be sent until after the public beta has begun.

We updated the [FAQ section on commitment](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#commitment) to explain it a little more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

To be accurate the e-mail doesn't say that the site has gone live. It just says:

> Thank you for following through on your commitment to Web Applications!
>
> In the 14 days since Web Applications launched, the community has generated 940 questions (876 answered!), 2,588 answers, 2,723 users, and 3,660 views per day.
>
> Please share a link to the site with anyone you think might be interested in our community:
>
> http://webapps.stackexchange.com
>
> We hope you continue to visit Web Applications and help it grow into a vibrant, useful community that benefits the internet at large.
>
> All the best,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team
>
> p.s. Now that you've followed through on your commitment, you can commit to an additional site proposal! Check out the list at http://area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I just got a similar mail (for crypto.stackexchange.com). Are we really supposed to throw out the URL while it is still in private beta?